# Round only a specific value , while leaving others the same

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, df, where I would like to round the value, 1.5 up to 2, while keeping the others the same (ex. 0.5)

Data

```
col1    col2
5       0.5
5       1.5
1.5     0.5
```

Desired

```
col1 col2
5    0.5
5    2
2    0.5
```

Doing

```
df['df'].apply(np.ceil)
```

However, this rounds the entire dataframe. I am still researching. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case just `replace`

```
out = df.replace({1.5:2})
Out[80]: 
   col1  col2
0   5.0   0.5
1   5.0   2.0
2   2.0   0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

This should also do well:

```
to_round = 1.5
for col in df.columns:
    df.loc[df[col] == to_round, col] = round(to_round)
```

You could also feed it a list of numbers to round and then iterate over those as such:

```
to_round = [0.5, 1.5]
for col in df.columns:
    for element in to_round:
        df.loc[df[col] == element, col] = round(element)
```